# "Share Screen" iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

Can I show this "Share Screen" in my own app using iOS 6? Somebody that knows how?

[image: iOS Share Screen]

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'm afraid you are all wrong. I'm sorry for being this negative, but your wrong answers forced me to waste time in going for futile solutions.... instead you can use this code to achive this screen:

```
NSString* someText = self.textView.text;
NSArray* dataToShare = @[someText];  // ...or whatever pieces of data you want to share.

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController = 
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare 
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

The code is from Social.framework.

See this answer: [Using Apple icons with iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546574/using-apple-icons-with-ios-6)

Comment: Everything's correct except that it's not from Social.framework, but UIKit.framework (hence the UI prefix) so you don't have to link to Social.framework. And yeah, I can't believe all these nonsense answers.

Comment: @Ertai is Sharekit supports ios6 without any complications?