# Implementing this "share" action window (ios 6)?

Tags: sharekit, ios6

I'm trying to add this action window into my app:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/COPqT.png

I'm currently using Sharekit and I was thinking about going to Socialize, but this new iOS 6 "share" button would be perfect.

a.) Is it even possible?
b.) Can't find the documentation if it possible.
c.) What would the fallback be for those < iOS 6?

Comment: Looks like I found my answer, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418412/share-screen-ios-6

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* texttoshre = self.textView.text;
NSArray* datatoshare = @[texttoshre];  // ...or other kind of data.

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController = 
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] datatoshare 
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```