# equivalent to android's share intent concept for iPhone using titanium?

Tags: titanium

I want to add share content functionality in my iOS app. I am developing an app in titanium for iPhone. I want to add a share button that when a user clicks will open a dialog box contains many different option like Facebook, twitter, email , and print.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this has been included in the Appcelerator Framework, you are going to have to write a module

["Share Screen" iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418412/share-screen-ios-6)

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for this that wraps the Social.framework on iOS. Ive used it in my own apps and its quite nice. [Find it here.](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/3830?1114647916)

And a small example of how to make it work.

```
        var Social = require('com.0x82.social');
        Social.showActivityItems({
            activityItems : ["http://stackoverflow.com"]
        });
        Social.addEventListener('activityWindowClosed', function(e) {
            if (e.completed) {
                alert('Shared successfully');
            }
        });
```